# Javascript changes not seen

Tags: javascript

I have a jsp file that calls a javascript function in a separate .js file. I have made an amendment to the .js function (added an alert()) and re-run the program. The alert is not called therefore the method is not called. I have renamed the method so that I get an exception but the method is successfully called. I have cleared the cache on Chrome and nothing has changed. I am using IntelliJ + embedded Tomcat.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

```
<div id="names" style="width: 100%;"><script>myFunc();</script></div>

function myFunc(asString) {
    alert("hello");
    var s;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        s += "helloAgain";
    }
    return s;
}
```

EDIT: Ok, I've found the issue. Using Firebug, I can now debug into the writePax function but... there is no alert() function. So the version I have amended is not the version being used in the app - even though the version in my exploded war has the amended version (with the alert()). Anyone know why, even after clearing my cache, all browsers are using an old .js file?

Comment: What `myFunc()` is doing ? could you show your javascript code ?

Comment: Can you please post `myFunc()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app is using a static server to serve files and it's configured to use a static version of my .js file. I've pointed my app to use local files and it is now displaying the alert().

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but this will work

```
<div id="names" style="width: 100%;" onClick="myFunc()">Click Me</div>
```

You can try it out here http://jsfiddle.net/6rQpE/

Answer (score 0):

myFunc should be called as long as you put the JavaScript before the HTML.

JavaScript functions do have return values, but that's not how you insert text into the document. It has to be done entirely within JavaScript or with a framework to make it easier.

If you were using jQuery you could write something like

```
<script>
  var myFunc = function() {

    alert("Surely I was clicked");

    var htmlOut = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { htmlOut += "hello again<br>"; }

    // selects the element with "names" as the id
    // and changes the html to the value of htmlOut
    $("#names").html(htmlOut);
  };


  // this is a jquery convention, it will execute this code when the html is done loading.
  $(function(){
    $("button").click(myFunc);
  });

</script>
```

Then you would put

```
<button>Click me</button>
```

somewhere in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this as it shows in your example above I don't think you can call the function before declaring it in the file.

Example:

```
    <div id="names" style="width: 100%;"><script>myFunc();</script></div>
    function myFunc(asString) {
        alert("hello");
        var s;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            s += "helloAgain";
        }
        return s;
     }
```

Will not work.....

```
    function myFunc(asString) {
        alert("hello");
        var s;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        s += "helloAgain";
        }
    return s;
    }
     <div id="names" style="width: 100%;"><script>myFunc();</script></div>
```

Will.....

Hope that helps

Comment: But the calling function and the actual function are in 2 different files and they work. My only issue is that when I put an alert() in the function, it isnt output to the screen meaning an old version must be cached.